# Magento 2: How to display all Customer Group Price on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, product, price, customer-group

I would like to display all customer group price for that product on product detail page.

May be need to work on `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml`

So when user is not logged in they are able to see for this Group we have this prices.

```
$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$ProductObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$groupPrices = $ProductObject->getData('group_price');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($groupPrices);
exit;
```

After that, need to set Customer Group wise Promotion Price, then also display that.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the way to get

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */
$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

// START
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$productAllTierPrices = $_product->getData('tier_price');

$allTierPrices = array();
foreach($productAllTierPrices as $tierPrices){
    $groupname = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Group')->load($tierPrices['cust_group'])->getCustomerGroupCode();
    $allTierPrices[$groupname] = $tierPrices['price'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($allTierPrices);
exit;
// END
```

How to avoid `ObjectManager` in above code? If you know then can update the answer or post own.

Thanks

Comment: I have had success passing the "Registry" into my block class and accessing the current product from there. See thread: [How do I get the current product in Magento2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/147872/35040)

Comment: @Ankit, how can we get product price from the customer group

Comment: This does not work if the prices are set from Catalog rule. can anyone suggest on that?