# Magento 2 set Max Sale Quantity per storeview

Tags: magento2

I need the stock item attributt "maxSaleQty" in storview level and not in global level. 
I have create a new product attribute "maxSaleQtyStore".
Then I create a Plugin. This works if I set a static value. But I'm not able to get the current product - with his attributtes.

The load product code comes from [How do I get the current product in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/how-do-i-get-the-current-product-in-magento2)

Here my code of the Item.php:

```
namespace Vendor\MaxSaleQty\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Item extends Template
{

   protected $registry;
   private $product;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
                                Registry $registry,
                                array $data)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    private function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');

            if (!$this->product->getId()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Failed to initialize product'));
            }
        }

        return $this->product;
    }

    public function afterGetMaxSaleQty()
    {

        $maxSaleQty = $this->getProduct->getMaxSaleQtyStore(); // $productId; 
        return $maxSaleQty;
    }
}
```

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use getData method.

```
$qty_increments = $prod->getData('qty_increments_new');
```

Comment: this do not work.