# How to remove object manager

Tags: magento2, object-manager

Below is my code how to write this code without object manager.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //get current product
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
        $productId = $product->getId();
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/how-do-i-get-the-current-product-in-magento2

Comment: http://catgento.com/2016/11/24/magento-2-get-current-product/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have this code in a class.
If you do, you can do this.

change the class constructor and add `Magento\Framework\Registry` as a parameter.
Like this:

```
protected $registry;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->registry = $registry;
    ....
}
```

and now you can make your code look like

```
$product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
$productId = ($product) ? $product->getId() : null;
```