# Magento 2 add seo title suffix for every product page

Tags: magento2, seo, product-page, title, suffix

How can I add SEO title suffix for product page?

Comment: Did the suggested change work how you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You got a couple of options.

Admin Panel > Content > Configuration > HTML Head

[image]

Have you tried these?

Comment: When I used this approach to add " | My Store " to the title it also added it to the h1 on-page as well. I had to override Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml to remove it from the h1 on-page title but leave it in the title html head element.

Comment: I only want this for product and category page..... not for every page

Comment: In that case you are going to have to do some template work.  But also detect whether product currently selected using this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/147872/70343 or category currently selected using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41950564/10121426