# How to Get Current Product ID in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4

Help me with these two type please:

- Using object manager
- Using block

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/how-do-i-get-the-current-product

Comment: are you on the product page or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference link](https://extensionsninjas.com/how-to-get-current-product-id-in-magento-2.html)

**Using Object Manager**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
echo $product->getId();
?>
```

**Using Block**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BlockClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       array $data = []
      ) {
         $this->registry = $registry;
         parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

     public function _prepareLayout()
     {
           return parent::_prepareLayout();
     }

     public function getCurrentProduct()
     {
           return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
     }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using object manager

````
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
echo $product->getId();
?>```
````